# Select Widget options get from model database

Tags: django, django-models

I want use select widget get from model,
for example i have table "select name from table1", I want show output of the sql quires output to the select widget option,

please guide me guys

-Ganesh.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)?